# How to fix a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException error

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have created a C# WinForms project which calculates numerical values and writes them to an open Excel spreadsheet. The program works by allowing the user to open a spreadsheet in the Excel program. The writing is carried out by one method called `private void updateExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` which writes like so:

```
if (*in range*)
    MySheet.Cells[activeRow, activeColumn].Value = total;
```

This approach works like a charm, except when there is an unsubmitted change made in the. By unsubmitted change I mean when the user goes directly into the spreadsheet and changes the number in the active cell without finalizing the change with one of:

- pressing enter
- pressing tab
- pressing an arrow key
- clicking elsewhere

When I write to the affected cell once more with the program I get a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException error. The full text being:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in System.Dynamic.dll
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Dynamic.dll
>   Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))

Oddly enough, when the direct user change is finalized with one of the bulleted methods I get no error when I rewrite to the cell with the program. 
How do I remedy my program to avoid the COMException error?

I already tried following the msdn link: [How to fix 'Call was rejected by callee' error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772.aspx). I called the C# method updateCell_Click from the space labeled "Insert your automation code here."

Comment: Using the Excel interop feature while *also* making the UI visible is in general a pretty bad idea.  Now there are two programs that demand what the UI look like.  You can easily tell who is the bigger boss.  And deal with it with try/catch.

Comment: Yes, Hans is right.  The Excel interface will take precedence over the .Net stuff interacting with it.  You could of course use something like Application.Interactive = false, which should prevent the user from making changes to the Excel UI

Comment: @steveo40 My problem is that I need the user to be able to click in the Excel UI so that they can easily choose the right cell to write. This error has been very rare ( < 1/200 times), but I'll try implementing some try-catch statements and other error checks

Comment: Yep, try/catch is the only solution then as far as I know